# what version of python I should use to make games with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

What is the best version of python to work with pygame? Is it the last version of python? What version of python pygame do developers use?

Comment: Unless you have a special need, you should always use the most recent version of just about anything,

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, python 3.9 is the only version that isn't officially supported because it is still very new. (Although there is a pre-release version of pygame that does work)

As I said, python 3.9 is the very latest version but it is so new that pygame hasn't had time to be updated to support it.

I personally use python 3.8 for pygame development since its the newest version of python that works with the public release of pygame but there are probably lots of people who use versions all the way down to 3.5 or maybe even 3.4. Basically just use whatever you are comfortable with/have installed already and you should be fine.